# The place of control changes (telerik component)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, components, telerik

I have a problem with the component(telerik) in Windows Form C#. When I add a control, the place where I put the control gets messed up during the test run of the program and goes to another place, it is clear in the video.

I have tried all the ways, it only works like this if you manually enter the location of the control in the Formload

Comment: "it is clear in the video" - did you forget to reference an external link in your question?

Comment: You are referencing a video that is not part of the question

Comment: I've almost found the solution. When the screen scaling is set to 100%, the controls work fine, but when you set it to 125%, their positions get messed up.

Comment: Try setting `autoscalemode` to `none`. Also `tablelayoutpanel` is a useful way to arrange controls without overlapping.